# Serverless.com / CloudFormation: Properties "Retry attempts", "Maximum age of record" not set on an AWS Lambda EventSourceMapping to a DynamoDB Stream

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I'm trying to set the properties "Retry attempts" and "Maximum age of record" on an AWS Lambda EventSourceMapping to a DynamoDB Stream - via `serverless.yml` for the [serverless framework](https://www.serverless.com/).
When the stack is deployed, they keep the default values, and not the values I set. Help? Thanks

My code:

```yaml
name-of-serverless-function
handler: src/functions/my.handler
  events:
    - stream:
        type: dynamodb
        batchSize: 1
        maximumRetryAttempts: 2
        maximumRecordAgeInSeconds: 8
        arn: properWorkingARN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just sent a PR implementing property `MaximumRecordAgeInSeconds` 
 for Kinesis and DynamoDB streams: https://github.com/serverless/serverless/pull/7833

Answer (score 3):

What is your `serverless` version?

I am suspicious that you are using `serverless` version not supporting `stream` event syntax you are using.

For example, `maximumRetryAttempts` is supported from version `1.60.0`.

`serverless` usually just ignore the not supported syntax, not returning any error.

Try to check if your `serverless` version support what you want in [here](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) or just upgrade to the latest version and try again.

In addition, you can check `cloudformation` file `serverless` create to deploy your project in `.serverless/cloudformation-template-update-stack.json`. Check if the `cloudformation` is created as you expected with the file.

---Edit---

I found `MaximumRecordAgeInSeconds` seems not supported now in `serverless`. This is opened [issue](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/7042).